Got Invalid path and Account GET failed error when install openstack swift
I followed the official installation guide to build a openstack train version cluster on centos7, after I installed and configured  swift, got error report in swift list --debug output when starting the swift services.
INFO:swiftclient:REQ: curl -i http://controller.cloud.com:8080/v1/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7cca295fa537?format=json -X GET -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABmeuXXIaxStgwm2Mkz2ENVnlrBrTL7CEH7U65R3s70N9v0rUqqlEiLs9DnZarMnGFoLUWrOs8aLy7D9KwE85VGeQVBlG2cDfPOr09cIBWQzJb94zFssyZDxsUign3MA5E3eXpF1SXZ0IVAK5QACnDi0eGLLmtJBTqV9cReN-ATiUXjUNQ"
INFO:swiftclient:RESP STATUS: 400 Bad Request
INFO:swiftclient:RESP HEADERS: {u'Date': u'Tue, 25 Jun 2024 15:44:24 GMT', u'Content-Length': u'70', u'Content-Type': u'text/html; charset=UTF-8', u'X-Openstack-Request-Id': u'tx7dc2cabeb91448bdadad2-00667ae5d7', u'X-Trans-Id': u'tx7dc2cabeb91448bdadad2-00667ae5d7'}
INFO:swiftclient:RESP BODY: Invalid path: //srv/node/sdc/907/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7cca295fa537
ERROR:swiftclient.service:Account GET failed: http://controller.cloud.com:8080/v1/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7cca295fa537?format=json 400 Bad Request  [first 60 chars of response] Invalid path: //srv/node/sdc/907/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/service.py", line 915, in _list_account_job
    headers=req_headers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1796, in get_account
    delimiter=delimiter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1739, in _retry
    service_token=self.service_token, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 825, in get_account
    raise ClientException.from_response(resp, 'Account GET failed', body)
ClientException: Account GET failed: http://controller.cloud.com:8080/v1/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7cca295fa537?format=json 400 Bad Request  [first 60 chars of response] Invalid path: //srv/node/sdc/907/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7c
Account GET failed: http://controller.cloud.com:8080/v1/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7cca295fa537?format=json 400 Bad Request  [first 60 chars of response] Invalid path: //srv/node/sdc/907/AUTH_ff3670b933564614867b7c
Failed Transaction ID: tx7dc2cabeb91448bdadad2-00667ae5d7


My final steps were as follows:
-------  controller node ----------
swift list --debug
-------  storage node----------
swift-init account-server start
swift-init account-server status
swift-init container-server start
swift-init container-server status
swift-init object-server start
swift-init object-server status
[root@storage node]# pwd
/srv/node
[root@storage node]# ll
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 swift swift 6 Jun 25 22:37 sdc
drwxrwxrwx 2 swift swift 6 Jun 25 22:37 sdd
[root@storage node]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 893M     0  893M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    910M  4.0K  910M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    910M   45M  866M   5% /run
tmpfs                    910M     0  910M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   17G  7.2G  9.9G  43% /
/dev/sda1               1014M  189M  826M  19% /boot
/dev/sr0                 4.5G  4.5G     0 100% /run/media/maikale/CentOS 7 x86_64
tmpfs                    182M   12K  182M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    182M     0  182M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdc1                 50G   33M   50G   1% /srv/node/sdc
/dev/sdd1                 50G   33M   50G   1% /srv/node/sdd

